# Javascript TDD/BDD uiser interface. How to test a form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, tdd, bdd

I am trying really hard to find a way of testing a javascript user interface. That is a fancy form, with a few fields that are locked depending on checkbox clicks, with ajax population of selects, and so on. All of that + jQuery.uniform that makes the implementation harder.

I need some orientation, but I cannot find a single example I can base on. Does anybody do this kind of testing? How?

I am very confortable with tdd/bdd using rspec (ruby on rails). In fact, the project I am working on is fairly well tested, except for views and javascript.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Selenium WebDriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/). We use it in combination with [SpecFlow](http://www.specflow.org/specflownew/) to test some of the UI stuff.

To work with Java Script, check out [JavascriptExecutor](http://onlineseleniumtraining.com/how-to-work-with-javascriptexecutor-using-selenium-webdriver/).

Comment: Thank you for your reply @void Ray. In fact I had already tried selenium but it was very slow (at least when integrated with rails) and I didn't find any example of its usage regarding form validations.